# natbib renders proceedings entry citations wrong

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

If I render this minimalistic setup:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{article}


% Sophisticated citation.
% Check out: http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}

\citep{zhuang2006}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

With this references.bib:

```
@proceedings {zhuang2006,
    author = {Li Zhuang and Feng Jing and Xiao-Yan Zhu},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the ACM 15th Conference on Information and Knowledge Management},
    title = {Movie review mining and summarization},
    publisher = {ACM},
    month = {nov},
    year = {2006},
    pages = {43-50},
}
```

Then I get this output:

[image: (zhu, 2006)]

But I want it to be more like this one, which apparently only applies for `article` entries rather than `proceedings` entries in the references.bib:

[image: (Zhuang et al., 2006)]

How can I do that?

Comment: Incidentally, there's a minor mistake in the `booktitle` field: it should be "...15th International Conference...", not just "...15th Conference...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* blame `natbib`. `natbib` is a citation management package. As such, its work is quite unrelated to the way bibliographic entries get formatted.

The real problem lies in the fact that you're using an inappropriate entry type, viz.,  `@proceedings`. The remedy lies in changing `@proceedings` to `@inproceedings`. Then, rerun BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs.

An MWE (minimum working example):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@inproceedings{zhuang2006,
  author    = "Li Zhuang and Feng Jing and Xiao-Yan Zhu",
  booktitle = "Proceedings of the ACM 15th International Conference
               on Information and Knowledge Management",
  title     = "Movie review mining and summarization",
  publisher = "ACM",
  month     = nov,
  year      = 2006,
  pages     = "43-50",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\citep{zhuang2006}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And also make the names in the `.bib` entry `Last name, First name` (Not strictly necessary, but good practice to get into for the OP.)

Comment: Thank you! I had the `@proceedings` from [some wiki page I found on Google](https://www.openoffice.org/bibliographic/bibtex-defs.html) but I guess that one is not accurate for latex's bibtex parser. Also thanks for the suggestion, @Alan Munn .

Comment: @AlanMunn -- Good suggestion to the OP, about being extra careful about what's the given (or "first") name component and what's the surname component of an author's "full" name.